# Openpose failed on AWS Deep learning instance. Then which instance can 100% run it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cmake, deep-learning

I have tried to build Openpose C++ source on AWS p3.2xlarge instance with AWS Deep Learning AMI https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077GCH38C?qid=1530671113739&sr=0-2&ref_=srh_res_product_title

The OS was Ubuntu 16.04 with almost all the prerequisites preinstalled (CUDA, cuDNN, OpenCV, Caffe).
I followed the official instruction in order to get it work.
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#operating-systems

This is the main error message I got when I tried to build it with cmake.
Does it mean that the GPU architecture is too new for openpose so that it can't compile? Anyone can explain the error I got?

**nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70'**

Is that any possibility of something wrong in the step before the build?

Finally I want to know what kind of environment really can run openpose, especially for AWS. Any report is appreciated.

The whole error message is here btw.

> src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/hand/openpose_generated_renderHand.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/hand/openpose_generated_renderHand.cu.o]
>   Error 1 make[2]: * Waiting for unfinished jobs.... nvcc fatal :
>   Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake Error at
>   openpose_generated_bodyPartConnectorBase.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
>   Error generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/./openpose_generated_bodyPartConnectorBase.cu.o
>
> nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70'
>   src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/openpose_generated_bodyPartConnectorBase.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/openpose_generated_bodyPartConnectorBase.cu.o]
>   Error 1 CMake Error at openpose_generated_maximumBase.cu.o.cmake:207
>   (message): Error generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/./openpose_generated_maximumBase.cu.o
>
> src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/openpose_generated_maximumBase.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/openpose_generated_maximumBase.cu.o]
>   Error 1 nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake
>   Error at openpose_generated_renderPose.cu.o.cmake:207 (message): Error
>   generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/./openpose_generated_renderPose.cu.o
>
> nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake Error at
>   openpose_generated_renderFace.cu.o.cmake:207 (message): Error
>   generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/face/./openpose_generated_renderFace.cu.o
>
> src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/openpose_generated_renderPose.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/pose/openpose_generated_renderPose.cu.o]
>   Error 1 nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake
>   Error at openpose_generated_resizeAndMergeBase.cu.o.cmake:207
>   (message): Error generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/./openpose_generated_resizeAndMergeBase.cu.o
>
> src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/face/openpose_generated_renderFace.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/face/openpose_generated_renderFace.cu.o]
>   Error 1 src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:112: recipe
>   for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/openpose_generated_resizeAndMergeBase.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/net/openpose_generated_resizeAndMergeBase.cu.o]
>   Error 1 nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake
>   Error at openpose_generated_pyramidalLK.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
>   Error generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/tracking/./openpose_generated_pyramidalLK.cu.o
>
> src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/tracking/openpose_generated_pyramidalLK.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/tracking/openpose_generated_pyramidalLK.cu.o]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:179: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/all' failed make[1]: *
>   [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: ***
>   Waiting for unfinished jobs.... [ 8%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/bvhSaver.cpp.o
>   Scanning dependencies of target openpose_gpu Scanning dependencies of
>   target openpose_thread [ 8%] Building NVCC (Device) object
>   src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/openpose_hand_generated_renderHand.cu.o
>   [ 9%] Building NVCC (Device) object
>   src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/openpose_face_generated_renderFace.cu.o
>   Scanning dependencies of target openpose_calibration [ 9%] Building
>   CXX object
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/cocoJsonSaver.cpp.o
>   [ 9%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/defineTemplates.cpp.o
>   [ 10%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/thread/CMakeFiles/openpose_thread.dir/defineTemplates.cpp.o
>   [ 11%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/cameraParameterEstimation.cpp.o
>   [ 11%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/gridPatternFunctions.cpp.o
>   nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake Error at
>   openpose_hand_generated_renderHand.cu.o.cmake:207 (message): Error
>   generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir//./openpose_hand_generated_renderHand.cu.o
>
> nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_70' CMake Error at
>   openpose_face_generated_renderFace.cu.o.cmake:207 (message): Error
>   generating
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/build/src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir//./openpose_face_generated_renderFace.cu.o
>
> src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/build.make:63: recipe
>   for target
>   'src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/openpose_hand_generated_renderHand.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/openpose_hand_generated_renderHand.cu.o]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:344: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/all' failed make[1]: *
>   [src/openpose/hand/CMakeFiles/openpose_hand.dir/all] Error 2
>
> src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/build.make:63: recipe
>   for target
>   'src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/openpose_face_generated_renderFace.cu.o'
>   failed make[2]: *
>   [src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/openpose_face_generated_renderFace.cu.o]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:456: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/all' failed make[1]:
>   [src/openpose/face/CMakeFiles/openpose_face.dir/all] Error 2 [ 12%]
>   Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/fileSaver.cpp.o
>   [ 12%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/fileStream.cpp.o
>   [ 12%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/gpu/CMakeFiles/openpose_gpu.dir/cuda.cpp.o In file
>   included from
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/include/openpose/filestream/headers.hpp:9:0,
>   from
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/src/openpose/filestream/defineTemplates.cpp:1:
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/include/openpose/filestream/fileStream.hpp:54:32:
>   error: ‘CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY’ was not declared in this scope =
>   {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100, CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9}); ^
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/build.make:110:
>   recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/defineTemplates.cpp.o'
>   failed make[2]:
>   [src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/defineTemplates.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 make[2]: Waiting for unfinished jobs.... [ 13%] Building CXX
>   object src/openpose/gpu/CMakeFiles/openpose_gpu.dir/gpu.cpp.o In file
>   included from
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/src/openpose/filestream/fileStream.cpp:7:0:
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/include/openpose/filestream/fileStream.hpp:54:32:
>   error: ‘CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY’ was not declared in this scope =
>   {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100, CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9}); ^
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
>   src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/build.make:158:
>   recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/fileStream.cpp.o'
>   failed make[2]:
>   [src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/fileStream.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 [ 13%] Building CXX object
>   src/openpose/gpu/CMakeFiles/openpose_gpu.dir/opencl.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:234: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/all'
>   failed make[1]:
>   [src/openpose/filestream/CMakeFiles/openpose_filestream.dir/all] Error
>   2 In file included from
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/src/openpose/calibration/cameraParameterEstimation.cpp:11:0:
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/include/openpose/filestream/fileStream.hpp:54:32:
>   error: ‘CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY’ was not declared in this scope =
>   {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100, CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9}); ^
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
>   src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/build.make:62:
>   recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/cameraParameterEstimation.cpp.o'
>   failed make[2]:
>   [src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/cameraParameterEstimation.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 make[2]: Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/src/openpose/calibration/gridPatternFunctions.cpp:
>   In function ‘void
>   op::improveCornersPositionsAtSubPixelLevel(std::vector >&, const
>   cv::Mat&)’:
>   /home/ubuntu/openpose/src/openpose/calibration/gridPatternFunctions.cpp:22:52:
>   error: ‘CV_TERMCRIT_EPS’ was not declared in this scope
>   cv::TermCriteria{ CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 1e-9 }); ^
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
>   src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/build.make:86:
>   recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/gridPatternFunctions.cpp.o'
>   failed make[2]:
>   [src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/gridPatternFunctions.cpp.o]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:511: recipe for target
>   'src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/all'
>   failed make[1]: *
>   [src/openpose/calibration/CMakeFiles/openpose_calibration.dir/all]
>   Error 2 [ 13%] Linking CXX shared library libopenpose_gpu.so [ 13%]
>   Built target openpose_gpu [ 13%] Linking CXX shared library
>   libopenpose_thread.so [ 13%] Built target openpose_thread
>   Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS p3 instance has Tesla V100 that require CUDA 9 and later.
But OpenPose require CUDA 8.

If you want to use OpenPose on AWS, you have to use p2 instance.